pandas search across multiple columns return one column if matches
Example data:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 6, 3, 9],
    'b': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'c': [10, 20, 30, 40],
    'd': [100, 200, 300, 400]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'm': [1, 5, 3, 7],
    'n': [2, 6, 8, 4],
    'o': [9, 10, 11, 12]
})

Requirement: 
df1['a'] can occur anywhere of df2. I want to return df2['m'] irrespective of where the match is found.
After some googling and chatGpt, I found melting df2 and merging with df1 is helpful except for it doesn't check for a match in df2['m'].
Code:
df2_melted = df2.melt(id_vars=['m'], value_vars=['n', 'o'])
merged_df = df1.merge(df2_melted, left_on='a', right_on='value', how='left')
df1['e'] = merged_df['m']
print(df1)

Output:
a  b   c    d    e
1  A  10  100  NaN     # df1['a'] == df2['m']
6  B  20  200  5.0     # df1['a'] == df2['n']
3  C  30  300  NaN     # df1['a'] == df2['m']
9  D  40  400  1.0     # df1['a'] == df2['o']

Required Output:
a  b   c    d  e
1  A  10  100  1
6  B  20  200  5
3  C  30  300  3
9  D  40  400  1

If df2['m'] could also be added to value_vars while melting, it'd have resolved the issue. I tried it, it didn't work. Then checked docs, found that whatever is there in the id_vars, the remaining or a subset of the remaining can be part of value_vars. So this approach might not be correct or I'm missing something.
Then I thought, if df1['a'] matches df2['m'], then df1['e'] == df1['a'] == df2['m']. So just replacing NaN value with df1['a'] should work and it worked. But had to convert the column to int; because of NaN, it's changed to float.
Working complete Code:
df2_melted = df2.melt(id_vars=['m'], value_vars=['n', 'o'])
merged_df = df1.merge(df2_melted, left_on='a', right_on='value', how='left')
df1['e'] = merged_df['m']
df1['e'] = (df1['e'].fillna(df1['a'])).astype(int)

Seemed like even though it's a working solution, it's unnecessarily complicated: "try any solution: add more code to fix the issues as you proceed without changing the initial solution".
Any other better approach which can help with my requirement?
 
PS1: In above example, it's not mandatory that df1 and df2 will have the same number of rows.

I didn't understand why the last row "E" column of required output has 1. Shouldnt it be 7?

@PawanTolani df1 column a row 4 contains 9 which equals to df2 column o row 1. So it'll assign df2 column m row 1 value to df1 column e row 4 as per the requirement which equals to 1: irrespective of where ever the match is found, the returned value is same row column m.

Just duplicate the column m as a new column before melt (also use map instead of merge):
df1['e'] = df1['a'].map(df2.eval('e=m').melt('e')
                           .set_index('value')['e'])

Variant with merge:
out = df1.merge(df2.assign(e=df2['m'])
                   .melt('e', value_name='a')
                   [['a', 'e']]
               )

Output:
   a  b   c    d  e
0  1  A  10  100  1
1  6  B  20  200  5
2  3  C  30  300  3
3  9  D  40  400  1


That's a nice one-liner with map. Can you please explain what you did there?

map is just the way to merge when you have a single key and a single column to assign. In short, one creates a Series with the key as index. See merge 101 for more info.

Thanks. That is helpful, also i tried your solution part by part and understood properly.
