pandas eval: creating column names with spaces giving odd names
My df contains columns m 1 and n.
I was trying to create a duplicate of column m 1 as m 2 using eval. Came across this thread which suggested to use backticks (`). So I used
df2.eval('`m 2` = `m 1`')

Now this is creating the duplicate column, but the column name is BACKTICK_QUOTED_STRING_m_2 instead of m 2. Backticks for the source m 1 worked fine and it took the correct column; But did not properly work for the target column.
I did a bit of googling, didn't get anything. Then I asked copilot, it suggested to use assign instead of eval. So my query is, is it possible to use eval for the above case?

it is intersting that DataFrame itself depends pd.eval to perform eval and whille df2.eval('m 2=m 1') succesfully returns a valid dataframe with bad named columns  pd.eval('m 2 = m 1 ') raise a ValueError i.e. ValueError: cannot assign without a target object  

Why not use assign? It doesn't accept all values but it is more flexible than eval.
df2.assign(**{'m 2': lambda x: x['m 1']})

Alternatively, rename and join:
df2.join(df2['m 1'].rename('m 2'))

# or in chained commands:
df2.pipe(lambda x: x.join(x['m 1'].rename('m 2')))

And, of course, if you don't need to create a copy of use chained commands, the most straightforward remains to assign in place:
df2['m 2'] = df2['m 1']


It is actually a chained command similar to one of your answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79019861/2381348.

Sorry it's my fault then, I rarely use eval I was lazy there ;)

A possible solution, which first creates the new column by using a name without any space (m2), and then renames it (to m 2):
df2.eval('m2 = `m 1`').rename(columns={'m2': 'm 2'})

Output:
   m 1  m 2
0    1    1
1    2    2
2    4    4


but the question is asking why df2.eval('`m 2` = `m 1`') creates BACKTICK_QUOTED_STRING_m_2 instead of m 2 and isnnit seeking for answer to rename the dataFrame

Thanks for your comment, @steve-ed. True, but since that appears to be not possible, the OP might be just happy with a workaround.

Maybe someone else did...
